# IBM WebSphere equivalent work manager in spring junit test suite

Tags: spring, junit, websphere, integration-testing, spring-test

We have an application which is deployed on WAS server. We use WAS work manager for mutli-threading. 
As of now we don't test multithreading and we just use mock of class com.ibm.websphere.asynchbeans.WorkManager binded in Spring context.

Now I have to write test cases for the same. These are integration test. Is there any ready to use implementation of IBM work manager which I can use as it is to provide same environment/ features. I found ready to use implementations of commonj work manager but not for IBM one.

Thanks
Sourabh